# How can i select from several tables with similar name?

Tags: mysql

as the question says, how can i select from several tables with similar names

for example, my tables are names m1, m2, all the way to m50 and all of them contain the same 2 columns... date and id.

ive done this

> select t.*, t.rowid from m4 t where t.DATE =
>   '10-sep-2015' and t.ID='76'

what i want to do is to search date and id in all the m# tables without having to change the table name every time i run the query...

also im very new to this type of stuff

thanks.

Comment: It looks like a really bad design, but if you really need it, use a for loop to generate select statements and join them with UNION

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Tables in mysql cant be manipulated dynamically. Instead of using sql, why not use a programming language and use regex patterns in table and loop OR PreparedStatement ?

Comment: didnt know that about mysql, i guess ill have to try something else